# Need to reference External script from Inside another External .JS file

Tags: javascript

I have an ecommerce site and I am creating a script that will determine the country that my user is in , and if it is one of the four countries we ship to then we will return a statement saying we ship to that country.  I was able to achieve this with a ip location service script ("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json callback=GetUserInfo") and my script combined in an html document, but now that I have attempted to move the script to sn external .js document I can not figure out how to  get my script to initiate the ip location service script.

**Original HTML Document(Working)**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Get User Country</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var strcountry
function GetUserInfo(data) {
strip = data.host;
strcountry = data.countryName;
}

$(function ()
{
BindUserInfo();
})
function BindUserInfo()
{
document.getElementById('lblCountry').innerHTML = strcountry;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
</head>
<body>


<a id="weship"/>


<script type="text/javascript">


if (strcountry == "United States")
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to The United States';
}

else if (strcountry == "Singapore") 
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Singapore';
}

else if (strcountry == "Malaysia") 
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Malaysia';
}
else if (strcountry == "Hong Kong") 
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Hong Kong';
}

</script>
```

**New HTML File Calling Script(index.html)**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Get User Ountry </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a id="weship"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="countrylocate.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**My Script(countrylocate.js)**

```
var strcountry

function GetUserInfo(data) {
        strip = data.host;
        strcountry = data.countryName;
         }

$(function ()
{
BindUserInfo();
})
function BindUserInfo()
{
document.getElementById('lblCountry').innerHTML = strcountry;
}

if (strcountry == "United States")
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to The United States';
}

else if (strcountry == "Singapore") 
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Singapore';
}

else if (strcountry == "Malaysia") 
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Malaysia';
}
else if (strcountry == "Hong Kong") 
{
    document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Hong Kong';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL for the location script:

```
http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo
```

I see `callback=GetUserInfo`.  This implies that the script requires that this function exists prior to it being called.  Since you have now moved this function **after** the script, it cannot call it.  You will need 2 separate external scripts.  One called before to set up the appropriate functions and one after to use the result.

As an alternative, you might consider checking with this service to see if it can be called in another manner.  Perhapse a `jsonp` call through jquery's `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts are out of order. Here is what you need.

Html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Get User Ountry </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<label id="lblCountry"></label>
<a id="weship"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/countrylocate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Modify countrylocate.js to this:

```
function GetUserInfo(data) {
    strip = data.host;
    strcountry = data.countryName;

    document.getElementById('lblCountry').innerHTML = strcountry;

    if (strcountry == "United States") {
        document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to The United States';
    }

    else if (strcountry == "Singapore") {
        document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Singapore';
    }

    else if (strcountry == "Malaysia") {
        document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Malaysia';
    }
    else if (strcountry == "Hong Kong") {
        document.getElementById('weship').innerHTML = 'We ship to Hong Kong';
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case `strcountry` will not be set prior to checking its value in the `if` statements.

Comment: Call BindUserInfo from GetUserInfo rather than at document ready time.